# function to return regular expression matches in mysql like preg_match return array in php

Tags: mysql, regex

I've table with data like

```
ticketid  | comments
----------------------
1234      | >
> Ticket ID:TT19027
>
> Ticket Title:report debug
>
>
4567      |>
> Ticket ID:TT19028
>
> Ticket Title:report debug
>
>
```

I'm looking for a function or query that will return

```
ticketid  | ticket_no_part_of_comments
1234      | TT19027
4567      | TT19028
```

I'm able to use clause like

```
comments regexp 'Ticket ID:([0-9]*)'
```

but it just returns 1 or 0.

Any suggestions.

Thanks in advance,
Anitha

Answer (score 0):

Get substing of `":"` in comment column.

You must get string after first `":"` character.

```
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', 2);
        -> 'www.mysql'
mysql> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mysql.com', '.', -2);
        -> 'mysql.com'
```

More information about *String functions* you can find at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Your solution is:

```
SELECT ticketid, SUBSTRING_INDEX(comments, ':', -2) as ticket_no_part_of_comments FROM your_table
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this wont work for me because I wont know the length of the ticket id that I'm looking for and there might be lot of ':'s in the comments field.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the preg user-defined functions for MySQL on [the MySQL UDF site](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/) as there's likely to be something useful there.